# pH responsive polymer which is immiscible in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, ph, polymers, immiscibility

Can anyone suggest a pH-responsive polymer, which is immiscible in water (polar solvent) but miscible in oil (e.g vegetable oil)?

I want to study the change in the density of such polymers when they are subjected to changing pH.

**Edit:**

I'm having a biphasic system of oil & water, and want to study the viscosity changes of oil with time!

For this, I was earlier thinking of having a polymer in the oil phase itself and somehow triggering (changing) its state of polymerization (density) by changing the pH of the underlying aqueous solution! (remember it's a biphasic system of oil & water).

But after reading some more papers and getting help from the underlying comments, I think it's not possible to have a polymer in an aprotic phase and then be able to study its response towards changing pH!

So now I have thought to change the experiment to synthesis a polymer at the biphasic boundary (surface) of the water and oil phase. This polymer must be soluble in the oil phase! Hence the product of interfacial polymerization must diffuse into the oil phase.

Comment: pH is a quantity that makes no sense in an aprotic solvent.

Comment: And what is that polymer supposed to do? "responsive" could mean it turns green. ?!?

Comment: You could've read the very next line, where I talk about density variation with pH.

Comment: pH change doesn't mean anything in an aprotic solvent, but I am only talking about pH with respect to the polymer. I understand that reading and understanding is not a part of Chemistry 101, but you might've learned that in grade 1!

Comment: There's no such thing as "pH with respect to the polymer". If you're referring to the *protonation state* of the polymer, then you may [edit] that in. By the way, it's not immediately obvious that your two sentences are linked; my suggestion would be to make that clearer. It could very well be that you are interested in studying the density of polymers that respond to "pH" (or protonation state) in other ways. More clarity usually means you get more chance of a helpful answer; I'm trying to help you here.

Comment: Actually I'm not a student of polymer science, but I feel it's a very nice area to explore since it has a huge lot of customization capabilities! I refer to "pH with respect to polymers" because I was recently reading a research paper titles "pH-responsive polymers" DOI: 10.1039/c6py01872f

Comment: Please have a look at the edits! Thanks