# Polymers which are miscible in oil

Tags: solubility, polymers, reference-request, solvents

Can someone suggest me a list of polymers or some paper where I may find polymers that are soluble in oils like silicon oil, mustard oil, coconut oil, bean oil or petroleum ether, etc.?

Comment: There are many types of polymers, from elemental sulfur to  polyborazylenes. Be more specific.

Comment: Can you suggest to me how to look for these types? I don't want to single out some properties, since my research demands a holistic picture of things, rather than just simply looking at a certain set of polymers!

I would be very grateful if you would share some of your knowledge with me! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Plastics Design Library](https://www.elsevier.com/books/book-series/plastics-design-library) series include tabulated parameters for the variety of polymers.
One of such parameters is a PDL number rating from 0 to 9:

0: solvent dissolved disintegrated
1: decomposition
2: severe distortion; oxidizer and plasticizer deteriorated
…
9: highest resistance, no change

In the table below I assembled data on thermoplastics chemically unstable towards various oils with PDL numbers below 3:

$$
\begin{array}{lrcll}
\hline
\textbf{Polymer} & \boldsymbol{T/\pu{°C}} & \textbf{PDL} & \textbf{Oil} & \textbf{Resistance Note} \\
\hline
\text{CAB} & 20 & 0 & \text{spearmint oil} & \text{Limited Resistance} \\
\hline
\text{LDPE} & 20 & 1 & \text{aniseed oil} & \text{Not resistant; tensile strength at yield and elongation at break greatly reduced} \\
\hline
\text{HDPE} & 20 & 2 & \text{camphor oil} & \text{Not resistant} \\
\hline
\text{PP} & 100 & 2 & \text{two-stroke engine oils} & \text{Unsatisfactory/severe effect} \\
  & 20 & 2 & \text{turpentine oil} & \text{Not resistant} \\
  & 100 & 2 & \text{vaseline oil} & \text{Unsatisfactory/severe effect} \\
\hline
\text{LLDPE} & 20 & 1 & \text{aniseed oil} & \text{Not resistant; tensile strength at yield and elongation at break greatly reduced} \\
\hline
\text{PS} & 22 & 2 & \text{clove oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
  & 22 & 2 & \text{lemon peel and oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
  & 22 & 2 & \text{orange peel and oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
  & 22 & 2 & \text{pine needle oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
  & 22 & 2 & \text{spearmint oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
\hline
\text{SAN} & 23 & 2 & \text{citronella oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs} \\
  & 23 & 2 & \text{clove oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs} \\
  & 22 & 2 & \text{lemon peel and oil} & \text{Not resistant; plastic severely crazed; softened or dissolved} \\
  & 52 & 2 & \text{pine needle oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs} \\
  & 23 & 2 & \text{spearmint oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs} \\
\hline
\text{ABS} & 52 & 2 & \text{pine needle oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs}  \\
  & 23 & 2 & \text{spearmint oil} & \text{Severe attack; softened in few hrs} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

#### Acronyms

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{CAB} & \text{Cellulose Acetate Butyrate} \\
\text{LDPE} & \text{Low Density Polyethylene} \\
\text{HDPE} & \text{Polyethylene} \\
\text{PP} & \text{Polypropylene} \\
\text{LLDPE} & \text{Linear Low Density Polyethylene} \\
\text{PS} & \text{Polystyrene} \\
\text{SAN} & \text{Styrene Acrylonitrile Copolymer} \\
\text{ABS} & \text{Acrylonitrile Butadiene Styrene}
\end{array}
$$

#### References

1. *Chemical Resistance of Thermoplastics*; Woishnis, W. A., Ebnesajjad, S., Eds.; Plastics Design Library; William Andrew: Norwich, N.Y, **2012**.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your guidance! I will surely be referring to this book from now onwards! You may want to look at this question, which I did post before, in case you need some more insights towards the research I'm working on! 

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/ph-responsive-polymer-which-is-immiscible-in-water

Comment: Hey, I find an Alphabetical List of Exposure Media at the end of the book. What should be my strategy to detect which of these media are immiscible in water and will tend to float on water (i.e lower density)? Does this follow any trend, or are they only a few which would follow any such rule, or else I have to look at all of them individually? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @AnshumanSinha I suspect you have to look it up (miscibility) or even determine the density yourself experimentally for your samples as it might slightly deviate from one manufacturer to another.